# Icon at Subject-line scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, includegraphics, scrlttr2

I want to add a small icon right left of the Subject line in a `scrlttr2` file.
I already managed this for a `scrartcl` file, but don't now how to do this in a letter.
Can you help me?

The code from the `scrartcl.cls` is:

```
\newcommand{\unquad}{\hskip-1.3em\relax}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\picturetodisplay}{\includegraphics{Bilder/Spiel_Start.jpg}} 
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\unquad\unquad\picturetodisplay\quad}
\makeatother
```

Does anyone know, how the reference for the subject is called in `scrlttr2`?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=10pt, DIV 14]{scrlttr2}
\KOMAoptions{%
    locfield=wide, %
    fromalign=left,%
    fontsize=10pt, %
    parskip=half   %
}
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}

%------------------- It's all about this part -----------------------
\newcommand{\unquad}{\hskip-1.3em\relax}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\picturetodisplay}{\includegraphics{Bilder/Spiel_Start.jpg}} % This is the icon I want to use
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\unquad\unquad\picturetodisplay\quad}
\makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{blindtext}


\setkomavar{subject}{$\leftarrow$ There should appear the icon \glqq Spiel\_Start.jpg\grqq{}}
\begin{document}
    \setkomavar{fromname}{Me}
    \begin{letter}{Jon Doe}
    \opening{Hey,}
    \blindtext


    \closing{Thank You. Over and out}

    \end{letter}

\end{document}
```

The hacked `scrartcl` sections look like this:

[image: Hacked_sections]

Thank you
Michael

Comment: I mean somthing like the "seccountformat" in scrartcl

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add `\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}` at the point where you want to get the icon. Because I do not have your used image I simply used image `example-image-a.jpg` frpm package MWE (which must be installed but not called!).

See the complete code (I deleted your code of the code snippet because it is not needed/used here):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=10pt, DIV 14]{scrlttr2}
\KOMAoptions{%
    locfield=wide, %
    fromalign=left,%
    fontsize=10pt, %
    parskip=half   %
}
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomavar{subject}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}$\leftarrow$ There should appear the icon \glqq Spiel\_Start.jpg\grqq{}}


\begin{document}
    \setkomavar{fromname}{Me}
    \begin{letter}{Jon Doe}
    \opening{Hey,}
    \blindtext


    \closing{Thank You. Over and out}

    \end{letter}

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 2):

You could use variable `subjectseparator`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=10pt, DIV=14]{scrlttr2}% <- syntax changed: DIV=14
\KOMAoptions{%
    locfield=wide, %
    fromalign=left,%
    fontsize=10pt,%
    parskip=half,%
    subject=titled % <- added
}
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomavar{subject}{$\leftarrow$ There should appear the icon \glqq Spiel\_Start.jpg\grqq{}}
\setkomavar{subjectseparator}[]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[width=1.5em]{example-image}\enskip}}% <- added


\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Me}
\begin{letter}{Jon Doe}
\opening{Hey,}
\blindtext
\closing{Thank You. Over and out}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Additional remark regarding your `scrartcl` hack: if you use a KOMA-Script class, avoid the redefinition of an internal command. You could redefine `\sectionlinesformat` or maybe `\sectionformat` (depending on the desired result).